# How to join 3 tables with lambda expression?

Tags: c#, linq, join, lambda

I have a simple LINQ lambda join query but I want to add a 3rd join with a where clause.  How do I go about doing that?

Here's my single join query:

```
var myList = Companies
    .Join(
        Sectors,
        comp => comp.Sector_code,
        sect => sect.Sector_code,
        (comp, sect) => new {Company = comp, Sector = sect} )
    .Select( c => new {
        c.Company.Equity_cusip,
        c.Company.Company_name,
        c.Company.Primary_exchange,
        c.Company.Sector_code,
        c.Sector.Description
    });
```

I want to add the following SQL command to the above LINQ query and still maintain the projections:

```
SELECT
    sector_code, industry_code 
FROM
    distribution_sector_industry 
WHERE
    service = 'numerical'
```

The 3rd join would be made with Sector table & Distribution_sector_industry on sector_code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not clear how your two queries relate to each other - where would the join be?

Comment: Good point @JonSkeet.  I've update the question.

Comment: this might change your mind to use Linq rather than lambda: http://www.ienablemuch.com/2014/03/highfalutin-code-1.html

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Just a guess:

```
var myList = Companies
    .Join(
        Sectors, 
        comp => comp.Sector_code,
        sect => sect.Sector_code,
        (comp, sect) => new { Company = comp, Sector = sect })
    .Join(
        DistributionSectorIndustry.Where(dsi => dsi.Service == "numerical"), 
        cs => cs.Sector.Sector_code,
        dsi => dsi.Sector_code,
        (cs, dsi) => new { cs.Company, cs.Sector, IndustryCode = dsi.Industry_code })
    .Select(c => new {
        c.Company.Equity_cusip,
        c.Company.Company_name,
        c.Company.Primary_exchange,
        c.Company.Sector_code,
        c.Sector.Description,
        c.IndustryCode
});
```

Answer (score 18):

Okay, I can't see why you'd want to select sector_code when you already know it, but I think you want this:

```
var query = from company in Companies
            join sector in Sectors
              on company.SectorCode equals sector.SectorCode
            join industry in DistributionSectorIndustry
              on sector.SectorCode equals industry.SectorCode
            where industry.Service == "numerical"
            select new {
                company.EquityCusip,
                company.CompanyName,
                company.PrimaryExchange,
                company.SectorCode,
                sector.Description,
                industry.IndustryCode
            };
```

Notes:

- I've changed it into a query expression as that's a *much* more readable way of expressing a query like this.
- Although the "where" clause comes after the join, assuming this is a LINQ to SQL or Entity Framework query, it shouldn't make any difference
- I've lengthened the range variable names for clarity
- I've converted your other names into conventional .NET names; you can do this too in your model

Comment: Thanks @JonSkeet.  I admit that your way was much more concise & readable, but I'm learning lambda and I prefer that format.  Thank you.

Comment: @inquisitive_one: Why would you prefer something when you admit the alternative is more readable? It's definitely worth knowing both forms - and there's nothing sillier than a query expression when a single `Where` call would do fine - but you should use whichever form is more readable in the context, IMO. By the time you've got multiple joins, query expressions almost always win.

Answer (score 5):

For 4 Tables

```
var query = CurrencyDeposits
    .Join(
        Customers, 
        cd => cd.CustomerId, cus => cus.Id, 
        (cd, cus) => new { CurrencyDeposit = cd, Customer = cus })
    .Join(
        Currencies, 
        x => x.CurrencyDeposit.CurrencyId, cr => cr.Id, 
        (x, cr) => new { x.CurrencyDeposit, x.Customer, Currency =  cr })
    .Join(
        Banks, 
        x => x.CurrencyDeposit.BankId, 
        bn => bn.Id, 
        (x, bn) => new { x.CurrencyDeposit, x.Customer, x.Currency, Bank = bn})
    .Select(s => new {
         s.CurrencyDeposit.Id,
         s.Customer.NameSurname,
         s.Currency.Code,
         s.Bank.BankName,
         s.CurrencyDeposit.RequesCode
     });
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this...

```
var myList = ({from a in Companies 
join b in Sectors on a.Sector_code equals b.Sector_code
join c in Distribution on b.distribution_code equals a.distribution_code
select new {...});
```